# Extracting a zip file on node.js stuck on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using [this](https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip/) node module to extract zip files in my application. Have been using it for a while now. I've just realised that there are few files that can't be extracted on Windows. No issues on OSX and Linux.

The zips have a lot of files and folders within them. Extracting stops after a few files have been extracted and it stops with no errors or output.

The problem is not with all the zips, but only a few them.

I'm not a node expert so I don't really know how to debug this issue. Any way of detecting if the stream or pipe failing?

```
var zip = 'myfile.zip';
var target = 'myfolder';
var zipper = app.fs.createReadStream(zip).pipe(app.unzip.Extract({ path: target }));

zipper.on('close', function(e){
    onSuccess();
});

zipper.on('error', function(e){
    console.log('Error extracting: ', e);
    onError(e);
});
```

I'm aware that module isn't maintained anymore but it has been doing the job fine for ages but I am welcome to new suggestions.

Comment: Filenames in windows & unix type OS, are not 100% compatible.  So to rule this out, can you Unzip on windows manually..?

Comment: I can indeed with inbuilt extracter and winrar.

Comment: You can try yauzl [https://www.npmjs.com/package/yauzl ] npm package, I had used and its doing job properly.

Comment: Was just about to mention `yauzl` too, using a lib that's not been updated for over 6 years, sounds problematic.

Comment: True but I'm going away for 2 months today. It's my last few hours and changing things about now is problematic too :) Sadly this only started happening yesterday evening. I'll have a look at that module.

Comment: Have you made sure that the zips are not corrupt by trying the extraction with some tool?

Comment: I have, default windows extractor, winrar and 7zip. No errors and extracts fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have at last solved this issue! Thanks to a comment left on the php manuals 9 years ago [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php).

Issue was with directories within the zip containing a `\`. Windows will not extract folders containing a slash i.e. `myfolder\`. Unixy systems will.